# Large $k$ asymptotic of $\mathbb{P}[X=k]$, given the generating function $\mathbb{E}[z^X]$

Tags: probability, random-variables, asymptotics, generating-functions, distribution-tails

Consider a non-negative integer valued random variable $X$.

Suppose that we are given the generating function $\mathbb{E}[z^X]$,
but we do not have it in the form $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\mathbb{P}[X=k]z^k$. That is, we do not know the probabilities $\mathbb{P}[X=k]$.

Is there a way to obtain from the generating function the asymptotic tail probabilities of $X$? That is to say, can we find a sequence $(a_k)$ with $a_k\sim\mathbb{P}[X=k]$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "$a_k\sim\mathbb P(X=k)$ as $k\to\infty$"?

Comment: This is from the family of Bachmann–Landau notations. It means $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\mathbb{P}[X=k]}{a_k}=1$.